# jQuery draggable - using margin instead of left/top

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable, margins

when moving elements the draggable plugin will set left/top coordinates, would it also be possible using margin-left / margin-top instead?
this way i could avoid using position:relative/absolute. 
thanks

Comment: Please show some code/research work what you have tried ?